# How can one the find normal force of a block resting on a pool floor underwater?

Tags: thermodynamics, forces, water, buoyancy

There is the force of gravity on the block, the atmosphere, the water pressure o top of the block, but how about between the block and the floor? Would we calculate water pressure pushing up from the pool floor? Or do we ignore it?

Comment: What do you think? If the block is in direct contact with the bottom of the pool, is there any fluid pushing onto the bottom of the block?

Answer (score -2):

There is buoyancy force on the object. That force is not caused by water pressure but by density differences of object and fluid around it.
That force is acting on object even if object is at the bottom.